# Define function just for test in Clojure

Tags: testing, clojure, integration-testing

I am writing some tests in Clojure and I am wondering whether a `def`/`defn` inside `deftest` is seen from other `deftest` in other namespaces. I am also inclined to think that this is bad practice and there is a more idiomatic way to share test functions (to create mocks for instance). Is there?

At the moment, defining:

```
(deftest tests

  (defn- mock-element
  [is-valid]
    (reify...
```

Doesn't expose mock-element outside the namespace, or I am doing something wrong.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `def...`, I believe, always defines things at the top level of the namespace. However, `defn-` - note the minus sign - defines a function that, although it is defined at the top level,  is private to the namespace, so `mock-element` will never be seen outside the namespace.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I am looking for something that doesn't get defined when I switch off testing when rebinding \*load-test\*. Maybe this is already working...I am going to try.

Answer (score 1):

`def` is always global: if you want something local, use `let` or `letfn`:

```
(deftest tests
  (letfn [(mock-element [is-valid]
            (reify...)]
    ...))
```

Comment: No but this is not my goal, my goal is to have something "sharable" among namespaces but only when *load-test* is true.